# Find number of perfect paths

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms

Given N Vertices and M Edges. Each Edge connects two vertices.

**There is at most one way to move between each pair of vertices**.

Each vertex is either locked or unlocked .There is a perfect path between two different vertices if both vertices are unlocked, and are connected with each other by some way.

The question is What is the number of pairs of vertices, which have a perfect path between them and also What is the number of the vertices, which have at least one perfect path passing through that vertex.

NOTE : **There is at most one way to move between each pair of vertices, that is, the given graph is a forest**

EXAMPLE : Say we have 6 Vertices and 5 Edges.

A=[1,1,1,1,1,0] It shows that A[i]=1 if ith vertex is unlocked otherwise 0.

Let the connected pair of vertices are : (1,2),(1,6),(1,5),(2,4),(4,3)

Here ,Answer for first question is 10 and second one is 5.

Comment: Are you looking for a formula, in terms of the list of connected pairs and the list of unlocked vertices? That may be asking for a lot. Are you just looking for an (efficient) algorithm to calculate the answer for a given input?

Comment: @GerryMyerson If formula cant be derived so easily then i am searching for an efficent algorithm which can work efficiently where number of vertices are of range 10^5.

Answer (score 0):

Let $N(V)$ be the number of vertex pairs which has a perfect path in the tree rooted at $V$. Let $S(V)$ be a set of vertices. $x\in S(V)$ if $x$ is a decendents of $V$ and there is no locked vertex in the path joining $V$ to $x$.
Now for an arbitary vertex W with children $V_1,V_2,V_3...V_k$,

$N(W)=N(V_1)+N(V_2)+...+N(V_k)$ if W is locked.
$N(W)=N(V_1)+N(V_2)+...+N(V_k)+S(V_1)*S(V_2)*...*S(V_k)$ if W is unlocked.

Enumerating $S$ and $N$ for all vertex can be done in linear time by traversing the tree bottom up.

Comment: Could you explain with help of an example ?